# Pass an argument when routing through a view in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to pass an argument when routing in a Backbone.js application

Here is the transcript

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {  
    'toolSettings/(:action)' : 'toolSettings'
  }
});

var initialize = function() {       
  var app_router = new AppRouter;       
  app_router.on('route:toolSettings', function(actions) {                   
    toolSettingsRoute.route();
  });
  Backbone.history.start();    
};
```

On the UI I've a `<a href="toolSettings/target" />` link which would invoke the `toolSettingsRoute.route()`.

I want pass this `action` argument in the route method and i've to pass it to further proceedings.

I tried `toolSettingsRoute.route(action)` and it's not giving any error, though how do i use this argument in the toolSettingsRoute.js file

I'd like to know how we can pass arguments correctly and utilize them in the subsequent js

Answer (score 0):

One options is to define your route functions in your router and you can just pass the parameter in to that function:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'toolSettings/(:action)': 'toolSettings'
    },
    toolSettings: function (action) {
        // whatever
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**E X A M P L E**

http://jsfiddle.net/mreis1/Nt9tm/1/

```
 var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {  
            'toolSettings/:action' : 'toolSettings'                      
        },
        toolSettings:function (action){
          //do whatever you want to do with the action parameter
        }
    });
```